# My Kafka sink connector for Neo4j fails to load

Tags: java, neo4j, apache-kafka-connect

**Introduction:**

Let me start by apologizing for any vagueness in my question I will try to provide as much information on this topic as I can (hopefully not too much), and please let me know if I should provide more. As well, I am quite new to Kafka and will probably stumble on terminology.

So, from my understanding on how the sink and source work, I can use the FileStreamSourceConnector provided by the Kafka Quickstart guide to write data(Neo4j commands) to a topic held in a Kafka cluster. Then I can write my own Neo4j sink connector and task to read those commands and send them to one or more Neo4j servers. To keep the project as simple as possible, for now, I based the sink connector and task off of the Kafka Quickstart guide's FileStreamSinkConnector and FileStreamSinkTask.

Kafka's FileStream:

[FileStreamSourceConnector](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/198a43d84693153c0f0177b8314117525c05047b/connect/file/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/file/FileStreamSourceConnector.java)

[FileStreamSourceTask](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/198a43d84693153c0f0177b8314117525c05047b/connect/file/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/file/FileStreamSourceTask.java)

[FileStreamSinkConnector](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/198a43d84693153c0f0177b8314117525c05047b/connect/file/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/file/FileStreamSinkConnector.java)

[FileStreamSinkTask](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/198a43d84693153c0f0177b8314117525c05047b/connect/file/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/file/FileStreamSinkTask.java)

My Neo4j Sink Connector:

```
package neo4k.sink;

import org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef;
import org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.Importance;
import org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.Type;
import org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.connector.Task;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.sink.SinkConnector;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Neo4jSinkConnector extends SinkConnector {

    public enum Keys {
        ;
        static final String URI = "uri";
        static final String USER = "user";
        static final String PASS = "pass";
        static final String LOG = "log";
    }

    private static final ConfigDef CONFIG_DEF = new ConfigDef()
            .define(Keys.URI, Type.STRING, "", Importance.HIGH, "Neo4j URI")
            .define(Keys.USER, Type.STRING, "", Importance.MEDIUM, "User Auth")
            .define(Keys.PASS, Type.STRING, "", Importance.MEDIUM, "Pass Auth")
            .define(Keys.LOG, Type.STRING, "./neoj4sinkconnecterlog.txt", Importance.LOW, "Log File");

    private String uri;
    private String user;
    private String pass;
    private String logFile;

    @Override
    public String version() {
        return AppInfoParser.getVersion();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Map<String, String> props) {
        uri = props.get(Keys.URI);
        user = props.get(Keys.USER);
        pass = props.get(Keys.PASS);
        logFile = props.get(Keys.LOG);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Task> taskClass() {
        return Neo4jSinkTask.class;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Map<String, String>> taskConfigs(int maxTasks) {
        ArrayList<Map<String, String>> configs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < maxTasks; i++) {
            Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();
            if (uri != null)
                config.put(Keys.URI, uri);
            if (user != null)
                config.put(Keys.USER, user);
            if (pass != null)
                config.put(Keys.PASS, pass);
            if (logFile != null)
                config.put(Keys.LOG, logFile);
            configs.add(config);
        }
        return configs;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
    }

    @Override
    public ConfigDef config() {
        return CONFIG_DEF;
    }
}
```

My Neo4j Sink Task:

```
package neo4k.sink;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetAndMetadata;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.sink.SinkRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.sink.SinkTask;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.AuthTokens;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Driver;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.GraphDatabase;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Session;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.StatementResult;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.Neo4jException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;

public class Neo4jSinkTask extends SinkTask {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Neo4jSinkTask.class);

    private String uri;
    private String user;
    private String pass;
    private String logFile;

    private Driver driver;
    private Session session;

    public Neo4jSinkTask() {
    }

    @Override
    public String version() {
        return new Neo4jSinkConnector().version();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Map<String, String> props) {
        uri = props.get(Neo4jSinkConnector.Keys.URI);
        user = props.get(Neo4jSinkConnector.Keys.USER);
        pass = props.get(Neo4jSinkConnector.Keys.PASS);
        logFile = props.get(Neo4jSinkConnector.Keys.LOG);

        driver = null;
        session = null;

        try {
            driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, AuthTokens.basic(user, pass));
            session = driver.session();
        } catch (Neo4jException ex) {
            log.trace(ex.getMessage(), logFilename());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void put(Collection<SinkRecord> sinkRecords) {
        StatementResult result;
        for (SinkRecord record : sinkRecords) {
            result = session.run(record.value().toString());
            log.trace(result.toString(), logFilename());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void flush(Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsets) {
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        if (session != null)
            session.close();
        if (driver != null)
            driver.close();
    }

    private String logFilename() {
        return logFile == null ? "stdout" : logFile;
    }
}
```

**The Issue:**

After writing that, I next built that including any dependencies that it had, excluding any Kafka dependencies, into a jar (Or Uber Jar? It was one file). Then I edited the plugin pathways in the connect-standalone.properties to include that artifact and wrote a properties file for my Neo4j sink connector. I did this all in an attempt to follow these [guidelines](http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#connect-installing-plugins).

My Neo4j sink connector properties file:

```
name=neo4k-sink

connector.class=neo4k.sink.Neo4jSinkConnector

tasks.max=1

uri=bolt://localhost:7687

user=neo4j

pass=Hunter2

topics=connect-test
```

But upon running the standalone, I get this error in the output that shuts down the stream (Error on line 5):

```
[2017-08-14 12:59:00,150] INFO Kafka version : 0.11.0.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:83)
[2017-08-14 12:59:00,150] INFO Kafka commitId : cb8625948210849f (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:84)
[2017-08-14 12:59:00,153] INFO Source task WorkerSourceTask{id=local-file-source-0} finished initialization and start (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:143)
[2017-08-14 12:59:00,153] INFO Created connector local-file-source (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:91)
[2017-08-14 12:59:00,153] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:100)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding.
    at java.util.Properties.loadConvert(Properties.java:574)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:390)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.loadProps(Utils.java:429)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:84)
[2017-08-14 12:59:00,156] INFO Kafka Connect stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:65)
[2017-08-14 12:59:00,156] INFO Stopping REST server (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:154)
[2017-08-14 12:59:00,168] INFO Stopped ServerConnector@540accf4{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8083} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector:306)
[2017-08-14 12:59:00,173] INFO Stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6d548d27{/,null,UNAVAILABLE} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler:865)
```

Edit: I should mention that during the part of the connector loading where the output is declaring what plugins have been added, I do not see any mention of the jar that I built earlier and created a pathway for in connect-standalone.properties. Here's a snippet for context:

```
[2017-08-14 12:58:58,969] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:132)
[2017-08-14 12:58:58,969] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:132)
[2017-08-14 12:58:58,969] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:132)
[2017-08-14 12:58:58,969] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:132)
[2017-08-14 12:58:58,970] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:132)
```

**Conclusion:**

I am at loss, I've done testing and researching for about a couple hours and I don't think I'm exactly sure what question to ask. So I'll say thank you for reading if you've gotten this far. If you noticed anything glaring that I may have done wrong in code or in method (e.g. packaging the jar), or think I should provide more context or console logs or anything really let me know. Thank you, again.

Comment: Kafka Connect was not able to read in your properties file where you defined your connector configuration, which is the second argument to the `connect-standalone` startup command. I'd suggest looking for hidden characters in the file(none were in the content on this post), trying without your JAR(s) present on the classpath, and even trying a different empty file to verify it can at least be read in correctly, and then gradually adding lines one at a time until you've defined all of your configuration properties.

Comment: Or, try specifying the configuration file as a fully-qualified path in the startup command.

Comment: That was it! Thank you.

Comment: @RandallHauch  , Don't we need the consumer group details to be specified while creating a new connector ? How does it consume from the topic without a consumer group ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Randall Hauch, my properties file had hidden characters within it because it was a rich text document. I fixed this by duplicating the connect-file-sink.properties file provided with Kafka, which I believe is just a regular text document. Then renaming and editing that duplicate for my neo4j sink properties.